# What is the etymology of "блондиться"?

Tags: этимология, диалект

There is a word which is used in Yaroslavl, "блондиться", here's a [quote](http://www.yar.kp.ru/daily/24267/464092/):

> Блондиться – значит где-то долго находиться, отсутствовать. Но
>   оказывается, это слово чисто ярославское. Ни в каких других регионах
>   так не говорят.

I have a lot of friends in Yaroslavl so I can confirm that this verb is indeed casually used.

My question is - **when this word came to usage and what it's origin?**

Here what I've found so far. According to "Русский этимологический словарь" под редакцией Аникина, выпуск 2":

> Рус. `бландать` (бездельничать), воронежское "плутать"...Это слово и к `блондать` - блуждать и далее к `блындать` - слоняться (новгородское)

This actually give a hint (an old word that probably an evidence of that nasals were a thing in Slavic - a well known fact) but the question is still open.

Comment: I've never heard this word but I am not living in Yaroslavl :) But I can say that your article about Yaroslavl only words is not always correct, "кура" instead "курица" is very popular in Saint Petersburg and "баллон" as "трехлитровая банка" is used in Rostov-on-Don.

Comment: @demonplus баллоном банки называют и в Ярославле, это зуб даю,  да, автор немного перестарался с попытками записать всё в чисто ярославские диалектизмы, но знание моё  об этом слове основано не на статье ) я думаю что многих чисто московских слов я тоже не слышал )

Comment: все-таки это комсомольская правда :) москвичи не говорят баллон и это слово их удивляет

Comment: Ну раз зашла речь о родном городе... [Слова, словечки...](http://yarportal.ru/topic25679.html) - обсуждение на ярославском форуме. Много интересного (но и мусора хватает).

Comment: От себя: слово "блондиться" от других слышал редко, но в нашей семье оно использовалось, да и сам я им пользуюсь до сих пор. Правда, у нас оно применялось в более узком значении: "болтаться без дела, надоедая окружающим". И чаще всего я его слышал от мамы о её собственном брате примерно в таком виде: "Все мужики выпили и спят, а этого ведь не приложишь, и бу-удет блондиться (горестный вздох)". :))

Comment: Только что удосужился сходить по ссылке на статью, и понял, что Наталья БАЖЕНОВА тему "Слова, Словечки" там упоминает. (Рискну предположить, что из этой темы, по большему счёту, материал для статьи и взят). Ну да ладно.

Comment: А что не так с носовыми в славянских? В польском их целых два.

Comment: @bipll - никто не утверждал обратного

Comment: @bipll - Только в польском они и остались,

Comment: @YellowSky, никто не утверждал обратного. (c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Polish, there is a noun [błąd](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C5%82%C4%85d) [bwɔ̃n̪t̪] 'mistake' to which there is an etymological cognate in Russian, *блуд*, 'fornication'. But Russian has other words formed from the root *блуд* which are not connected with fornication, e.g. *за**блуд**иться*, the same in Polish, only without a prefix: [błądzić](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/b%C5%82%C4%85dzi%C4%87) [ˈbwɔɲ.dʑitɕ] 'to stray, to roam, to rove'. Pronounced with all the Polish sounds substituted for their nearest Russian equivalents it will sound as *блондить*.

In other words, your word *блондиться* is most probably a borrowing from Polish, the corresponding Russian equivalent would be **блудиться*. The sound correspondence [on]~[u] definitely says it is a Polish word.

Comment: I've updated the question. Not sure that this is borrowing though rather than a cognate which evolved indenpedently from Slavic.
Still good answer though.

Comment: I wonder whether валандаться share the same origin.

Comment: @shabunc - _Валандаться_ is a borrowing from Lithuanian, Lith. _valanda_ 'time period, hour'. Russian _валáнда_ 'sluggish person'. That's what Vasmer says.

Comment: @shabunc - I'm sure I'm right, the word is a borrowing from Polish. The original form was блѫдъ /blɔ̃dŭ/, and of all the Slavic languages only Polish has kept the nasals, so if in a modern Slavic word you see or hear a nasal reflex of an old nasalized vowel, you can be 100% sure the word is Polish or of Polish origin.

Answer (score 1):

The dialectic regional блондить originates from the idiom блыонды бить. In some dialects we observe idioms which are different in possessing either one or a combination of consonants in the first syllable. They are *лыОнды бить и блыОнды бить* 'бездельничать' which are equivalent to a well-known *бить баклуши*.

The idiom лынды бить 'бить баклуши, бездельничать' is used mostly in southern dialects, in Pskov region, Lithuania and Latvia and actively in Smolensk region where another variant is known : Олындьё бить'то же, что лынды бить' Смол., лúнду петь сидеть сложа руки, бездельничать'. In Orel, Bryansk regions they have лынды продавáть 'бесцельно бродить; слоняться' , лынды лындать 'вести праздный образ жизни'.

There is also a variant with **блыОнды** in some dialects блынды бить 'бездельничать'. The formal comparison shows the simplification бл- > л-.

The research showed that the idiom originated from the noun **лыОнда**--нога which is seen in several Slavonic dialects including Byelorussian and Polish:

Blr. лыОнды 'ноги', лыОндаць 'лентяйничать притаившись', 'бродить, шляться'; Pol. fynda 'бродяга', fyndac sif 'шататься, шляться'
Though M. Фасмер thought the word лыОнда, лыОнды, лыОндать was connected with Slavonic лынь 'лентяй, тунеядец' и лытáть 'лениться, лодырничать' , Ю.А.Лаучюте shows that the origin is Baltic considering the Lithuanian:

linda 'пронырливый человек; лентяй; тот, кто притаился, избежал работы' ,also: lindé ti '(прятаться, скрываться) торчать' .